# Pull data from table based on the date of the first record

Tags: sql, r, date

I am querying some data from a sql table based on dates entered by the user as below :

```
dt = as.Date(some_date)

# Manipulate dates
end_date = as.Date(dt)
begin_date = as.character(as.Date(end_date) - 364)
```

What happens after this is that all records in the table where the date field falls between the begin and end date are pulled.

```
qry <-  paste0("select * from table 
                 where date>= '", begin_date, "' and date <= '", end_date; ")
```

But sometimes it might happen that I do not have 1 years of data but only 10 or 9 or 8 months.
So I want to be able to change the 364 value as per the first date in the table.
So is there any way in R by which I can pull the records starting with the begin date as end_date - 364 and if that date does not exist in the table change the begin date to the first available date and run the query again.

I understand that this will require two passes of the dates and the query but I want to be able to do it iteratively without manually checking for the dates.

Comment: You might be looking for something like this - `qry <-  paste0("select * from table where date >= max('", begin_date,"', (select min(date) from table))", " and date <= '", end_date, "';")`

Answer (score 0):

Your query will give you one year of data or all the data available in `table`, which seems to be your requirement. However, if you need to know if there is more than one year of data before selecting the data, than you can use

```
SELECT MIN(date) FROM table
```

to get the earliest date available.